# How to share ASP.NET forms authentication in a IIS WebSite with a child virtual directory containing a SPA (just static files)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, forms-authentication

I have a legacy web application developed in ASP.NET MVC 2 and hosted on IIS 7 using forms authentication:

```
 <machineKey validationKey="XXX" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="YYY" loginUrl="/SignIn.aspx?" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="/main.aspx" domain="ZZZ" path="/" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true" />
 </authentication>
```

I am now creating a virtual application inside of this ASP.NET MVC web site, this is going to host a SPA (single page application) app that just contains static files. **I want to share the same authentication cookie and make sure that:**

- When the user is authenticated on the ASP.NET MVC, then it will be able to access my index.html inside my child virtual directory.
- When the user is not authenticated then it needs to be redirected to /SignIn.aspx.